# Aurelia validation not binding to textbox component

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I've made a simple textbox component that just wraps some styling and a combination of label and textbox. When I attempt to bind validation to this control using the typical binding syntax, the blur functionality isn't causing validation to execute.

The component view looks like:

```
<template>
    <div class="form-field">
        <div class="form-field__label">
            ${label}
            <input name.bind="name" id.bind="name" class="form-field__input" type.bind="type" value.bind="value" tabindex.bind="tabIndex"></input>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

And the viewmodel looks like:

```
import {bindable, bindingMode} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class Textbox {
    @bindable({defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay}) value : string;
    @bindable label : string;
    @bindable type : string = "textbox";
    @bindable tabIndex: number;
    @bindable hidden : boolean;
    @bindable name : string = '';
}
```

And the component is used like this:

```
<textbox value.bind="emailAddress & validate" type="email"></textbox>
```

The databinding is working as expected, but the validation binding isn't working.  Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The element needs to fire a blur event. Since your element is custom, you'll need to add code to fire it when it "blurs". In your case, this is pretty simple, there's only one focusable element in your custom element's template.

Here's an example: https://gist.run?id=06bda9ac6e068ad21dab7b470f69c566

**textbox.html**

```html
<template>
  <div class="form-field">
    <div class="form-field__label">
      ${label}
      <input name.bind="name"
             id.bind="name"
             class="form-field__input"
             type.bind="type"
             value.bind="value"
             tabindex.bind="tabIndex"
             blur.trigger="blur()">
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

**textbox.js**

```js
import {bindable, bindingMode, DOM, inject} from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(Element)
export class Textbox {
  @bindable({defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay}) value: string;
  @bindable label: string;
  @bindable type: string = "textbox";
  @bindable tabIndex: number;
  @bindable hidden: boolean;
  @bindable name: string = '';
  element: Element;

  constructor(element) {
    this.element = element;
  }

  blur() {
    this.element.dispatchEvent(DOM.createCustomEvent('blur'));
  }
}
```

We'll get this added to the docs: https://github.com/aurelia/validation/issues/297

Comment: Nice, knew it was probably something simple...works great.